# how to split a string with multiple delimeters in vba?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am trying to split a string. I am using the split function, but I am unable to do for multiple delimiters.

Course Details = Split("ENM/5200-Fall2014/aba","/")

Comment: So you also want to split on -?  or what's the output your looking for?

Comment: I want to split the string into separate parts. for Example       Course Details = Split("ENM/5200-Fall2014/aba","/")(0)                         should give a result  "ENM"

Comment: @jgritty The question is VBA, so (0) is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the replace function to change the - to / (assuming the - isn't used in other text)

for if you just have -

```
Split(Replace("ENM/5200-Fall2014/aba", "-", "/"), "/")
```

for if you have - and ( and )  it drops the )'s and only looks at the - (, but if we need to we can alter it so the "" has ")" to replace with "/" as well

```
Split(Replace(Replace(Replace("ENM/5200-Fall2014(aba)", "-", "/"),"(","/"), ")",")"), "/")
```

Comment: Thank you, But if my string can change into
Course Details = Split("ENM/5200-Fall2014(aba)","/"). How do I do it

Comment: the delimiters can either be / or - or (). How do I split it

Comment: You just nest the replaces for the different deliminators until you get down to one then you use the split. However, it MUST be that the string data doesn't use these delimiters for anything else anywhere in the string  Updated to include handling '-', '(', and ')' as deliminators.